# install django on centos 6 (sqlite3 error)

Tags: python, django, sqlite, centos6

I am trying to install Django 2.1 on Centos6 but I'v got no success.

according to [this issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29624) and this [documentations of Django 2.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/databases/), Django 2.1 needs SQLite 3.7.15 and later. 
after knowing this I tried to upgrade sqlite and sqlite-devel to 3.7.17 by CERT Forensics repo but nothing changed after upgrading to 3.7.17 and I still get this error at running server by manage.py:

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced). Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f7561c29950> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/root/django-project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()   File "/root/django-project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)   File "/root/django-project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 159, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params) sqlite3.NotSupportedError: URIs not supported

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/root/django-project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/root/django-project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()   File "/root/django-project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 442, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])   File "/root/django-project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)   File "/root/django-project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()   File "/root/django-project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()   File "/root/django-project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 61, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():   File "/root/django-project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 44, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())   File "/root/django-project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 255, in cursor
    return self._cursor()   File "/root/django-project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 232, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()   File "/root/django-project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()   File "/root/django-project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value   File "/root/django-project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()   File "/root/django-project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)   File "/root/django-project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 159, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params) django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: URIs not supported
```

I have no idea how to fix this error. looking forward to your advises.

***edited 1:

this is my database section in my django setting.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

I tried it by "sudo (my virtual environment python path) ./manage.py runserver" but got the same message.

I also checked it by removing the database section from setting.py file. in this case Django runs with no problem but I need sqlite as my database :D

***edit 2:

I use python 3.6.7. this is my python console and my internal sqlite version in python shell:

```
Python 3.6.7 (default, Dec  5 2018, 15:02:16)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.version
'2.6.0'
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.7.17'
```

Comment: What is your DATABASES setting? This doesn't seem to have anything to do with sqlite versions.

Comment: I keep is as default like this:

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

Comment: are you running it with sudo or as root? the error happens on `runserver` command?

Comment: i tried by running it by "sudo (my virtual environment python path) manage.py runserver" but i'v got the same error.

Comment: I think the main problem is python version. Because it always shipped with its own sqlite version. What's your python version?

Comment: I use python 3.6.7 (Dec  5 2018) witch is not more than 2 months old